# Can't figure out this rails error: undefined method `remember_token=' for #<User:0x00000005e44238>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I gave my app an authentication system by follow Michael Hartl's tutorial, but I keep getting this remember_token method error:

```
undefined method `remember_token=' for #<User:0x00000005e44238>
```

I don't understand why remember_token is undefined because Hartl's tutorial says it automatically generated by the remember method I believe.

Here is the application trace:

```
app/models/user.rb:23:in `remember'
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:10:in `remember'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

relevant user.rb:

```
def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                              BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
end

def User.new_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def remember
  self.remember_token = User.new_token
  update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))


end
```

sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    log_in user
    params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
    remember user
    redirect_back_or user
  else
     # Create an error message.
     flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
     render 'new'
   end
   end

   def destroy
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
    redirect_to root_url
    end
    end
```

relevant sessions helper:

```
def remember(user)
  user.remember
  cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end

def forget(user)
  user.forget
  cookies.delete(:user_id)
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end

# Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
  if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
    log_in user
    @current_user = user
   end
  end

 end
```

Comment: you can always check what columns exist in the db by looking at `db/schema.rb` - go look there and see if you have a `create table :users` and if one of the columns is called `remember_token` - if not... then something went wrong and you may need to run a migration for it. Note: adding `rememberable` only lets devise know to *use* an existing remember_token, unless you used it during the generator-stage

Comment: one of the columns is remember_digest?  I'm not using devise and either does Hartl in his tutorial, and that what I followed to implement my authentication

Answer (score 3):

I guess you skipped the part in which you had to add a new column `remember_token` to your database (see: Listing `8.16` on https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_in_out#cha-sign_in_sign_out)

If you did that step, you need to migrate your database and restart your server:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
$ touch tmp/restart.txt
```